# WPF DataBind DataGrid to XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Having issues getting the DataGrid to populate with the XML.

Here is an example of the XML string

```
<Document docID="Uplift">
<DocHeader>
<DocTitle>Hourly Uplift and Intertie Offer Guarantee Estimates Report</DocTitle>
<DocRevision>1</DocRevision>
<DocConfidentiality>
  <DocConfClass>PUB</DocConfClass>
</DocConfidentiality>
<CreatedAt>2014-04-01T16:03:23</CreatedAt>
</DocHeader>
<DocBody>
<DeliveryDate>2014-04-01</DeliveryDate>
<HourlyUplift>
  <DeliveryHour>1</DeliveryHour>
  <Uplift>1</Uplift>
  <IOG>0.02</IOG>
</HourlyUplift>
<HourlyUplift>
  <DeliveryHour>2</DeliveryHour>
  <Uplift>0</Uplift>
  <IOG>0</IOG>
</HourlyUplift>
```

Below is how i'm databinding the xml to the DataGrid in the XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element[DocBody].Elements[HourlyUplift]}" Margin="0,33,0,0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hour" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[DeliveryHour].Value}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is how I set up the xElement in the Code Behind

```
var List = XElement.Parse(xml);
        this.LibraryView.DataContext = List;
```

The issue is when I go to run the code the DataGrid is blank. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When working with Xml DataContext, it is easier to use XPath property instead of Path :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" Margin="0,33,0,0"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Document/DocBody/HourlyUplift}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hour" Binding="{Binding XPath=DeliveryHour}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Notice that slash (`/`) means "*direct child*" in XPath. Some other basic XPath notations are (`//`) for descendant and (`@`) for XML attribute.

And in code-behind, use `XmlDocument` instead of `XElement` :

```
var List = new XmlDocument();
List.LoadXml(xml);
this.LibraryView.DataContext = List;
```